# Plaxo Contact Widget message

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, plaxo

I used plaxo contact widget to pull gmail, yahoo mail contacts and many. It's working fine, but every time when I open that page it will show a popup window with the following error message:

> unable to add recipients . Please close the address book window and try again

Please suggest me what to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, we've retired our API Contact Widget and no longer support it as of October 31st 2011.. You can read more on our blog - http://blog.plaxo.com/2011/08/plaxo-widget-retirement/.

Thanks

p.s. You can try out cloudsponge.com :) (and you get a free trial if you mention Plaxo)